# Import error: No module named 'Crypto' on Mac (Pycrypto is up-to-date)

Tags: python, django, pycrypto

Pycrypto has been installed properly (At least to my knowledge. Everything is up to date and I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling with pip). I'm not sure what the issues are here but this code works on others' computers so it has to be something with my configuration specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/samantha/Documents/3rdyrdoe/semester2doe/cs3240-f16-team14/mysite/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    url(r'^myapplication/', include('myapplication.urls', namespace='myapplication')),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/samantha/Documents/3rdyrdoe/semester2doe/cs3240-f16-team14/myapplication/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myapplication import views
  File "/Users/samantha/Documents/3rdyrdoe/semester2doe/cs3240-f16-team14/myapplication/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed it to the correct python version? Have you tried it with `sudo pip-3.4 install pycrypto`?

Comment: I have, it's installed to the 3.4.

Answer (score 10):

There is a module named "crypto" that is causing the problem. At least for me, in Mac OS. There are two package names "crypto" and "Crypto" which causes this conflict.

Since you are using Python 3.4, try running the following commands to uninstall:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall crypto
sudo pip3 uninstall pycrypto
```

Then install the pycrypto module again using:

```
sudo pip3 install pycrypto
```

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. I fix it by following command:

```bash
pip uninstall pycryptodome
pip uninstall pycrypto
pip uninstall crypto
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Especially why the additional lines in comparison to the existing similar answer are necessary, or what advantage they provide.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm voting to delete this answer. Because this is essentially the same as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509467/7758804), I can only assume it was posted as a "thank you" or "confirmation". Please don't add "thank you", or "confirmation" answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/34245895)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip list` command to check if there is a module named crypto inside your package, if not try `easy_install Crypto` to install instead of pip.

Comment: It lists the crypto module inside the package. Any more ideas?